# Change URLs using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to change the href values of links in an HTML file but for some reason, it doesn't happend. Here is the part where I am trying to make it happen:

```
a['href'] = internal
```

Here is the description of the script

This script creates a list of all of the .html files in the folder. Reverse engineers what the corresponding web URL was (I have another script that downloads webpages and creates local versions). Opens each file one by one, finds URLs that are external linking and replaces them with local ones

```
import re
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def replace_links(destination):
    files = []
    external_links = [] 
    #r = root, d = directories, f = files
    for r, d, f in os.walk(destination):
        for file in f:
            if '.html' in file:
                files.append(os.path.join(r, file))

    for f in files:
        external_links.append(reverse_eng_url(f, destination))

    html(files, external_links)

def reverse_eng_url(origin_url, destination):
    return origin_url.replace(destination, "").replace("-","/").replace("\\","/").replace("html", "aspx")

def html(files, external_links):
    for local in files:
        #open and read content of each file
        with open(local, "r") as f:
            contents = f.read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, "lxml")
            # find links in each file that contain external links and replace them with internal
            for internal, ext in zip(files, external_links):
                #print ext
                for a in soup.find_all("a", href=re.compile(ext)):
                    #print a
                    print(a['href']) 
                    print(internal)
                    #------------------------The problem is here
                    a['href'] = internal #a[href] is found, internal also exists as a value, but for some reason internal doesn't get assigned to a[href]
                    #___________________________________________


if __name__ == "__main__":
    replace_links("C:\\Transition\\")
```

Comment: You're reading the file, but never writing to it.  Of course the file is not changed.

Comment: How would I write to the file so that the link gets changed?